# How to fix Value error "Length of Values (1) doesn match length of index (15)"

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

Workflow =>

- Read CSV file and get *Unit Price* column data
- Convert column data price and create a new column as name 'Fabric'
- save the output as xlsx

Sample:

```
Unit Price
----------
330
350
380

I want to convert this data 

Fabric
------
Card
Combed
Viscos
```

My code:

```
##Fabric Data 
getFabric = df_new['Unit Price']
result = []
for fabric in getFabric:
    if fabric == 310:
        result.append("Card")        
    elif fabric == 330:
        result.append("Combed Dawah")
    elif fabric == 350:
        result.append("Combed Regular")
    elif fabric == 490:
        result.append("Viscos")
    elif fabric == 550:
        result.append("Pleated")
    else:
        result.append(fabric)
    df_new['Fabric'] = result
```

Error :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Insted of iterating column value. Try this,**

**pandas built-in function** called `.replace()` is useful for replacing the value in the column without iteration throung it

```
df_new['Unit Price'].replace({310: 'Card', 330: 'Combed Dawah', 350: 'Combed Regular', 490: 'Viscos', 550: 'Pleated'}, inplace=True)
```

Above code will successfully relace the dataframe column values **inplace**.

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion, It's working fine but having issue that it's taking two column. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Which taking two column ?

Comment: Solved that problem also thank u

Comment: Would you mind to check this issue also,please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72340148/how-to-fix-pandas-column-data

Answer (score 1):

That's easy dude...

```
your_df["Fabric"] = your_df["Unit Price"].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace("330", "Card"))

# do this for every conversion

your_df.to_csv("filename.csv")
```

The above code can be saved as a CSV file that could be viewed in MS EXCEL