# How to fix pandas column data

Tags: python, pandas

Workflow is :

- Read CSV file using **Python's pandas library** and get **Variation** Column
- **Variation** Column data is

```
Variation
----------
Color Family : Black,  Size:Int:L
Color Family : Blue, Size:Int:M
Color Family : Red, Size:Int:Xl
```

- But I want to print this data in different column with sorted data and save its as a xlsx

```
Color        Size
-------      ------
Black           L
Blue            M
Red             XL
```

My code is :

```
#spliting variation data

#taking variation column data in a var
get_variation = df_new['Variation'] 


#Splitting Column data
for part in get_variation:
        format_part = str(part)
        data = re.split(r'[:,]' , format_part)
        df_new['Color'] = data[1]
        df_new['Size'] = data[4]
```

But my output is coming as

```
Color     Size
------   ------
Black      L
Black      L
Black      L
```

Comment: Hint: `data[1]` and `data[4]` are scalars. What happens when you assign a scalar to a column?

Answer (score 0):

Without mapping or iteration you can done using str `.replace()` function using pandas. Try this,

```
#replacing "Color Family : " to "" 
df['Variation'] = df['Variation'].str.replace("Color Family : ","") 

#replacing " Size:Int:" to "" 
df['Variation'] = df['Variation'].str.replace(" Size:Int:","")

#splitting by , to seperate (Color and Size) then Expanding Columns
df[['Color', 'Size']] = df['Variation'].str.split(',', expand = True)
print(df)
```

The output will be,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
df['Variation'].str.extract('Color Family : (?P<Color>.*?),\s+Size:Int:(?P<Size>\w+)')

   Color Size
0  Black    L
1   Blue    M
2    Red   Xl
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by me here is my snippet

```
# Color Column
color = df_new['Variation'].str.split(',' ,expand=True)[0]
df_new['Color'] = color.str.split(':' , expand=True)[1]

# Size Column
size = df_new['Variation'].str.split(',' ,expand=True)[1]
df_new['Size'] = size.str.split(':' ,expand=True)[2]
```

Thanks everyone who helped me